# Python robotparser module won't load 'robots.txt'

Tags: python, python-2.7, robots.txt, python-module

I'm writing a very simple web crawler and trying to parse `'robots.txt'` files. I found the `robotparser` module in the standard library, which should do exactly this. I'm using Python 2.7.2. Unfortunately, my code won't load the `'robots.txt'` files correctly, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the relevant snippet of my code:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin
import robotparser

def get_all_links(page, url):
    links = []
    page_url = urlparse(url)
    base = page_url[0] + '://' + page_url[1]
    robots_url = urljoin(base, '/robots.txt')
    rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    rp.set_url(robots_url)
    rp.read()
    for link in page.find_all('a'):
        link_url = link.get('href')
        print "Found a link: ", link_url
        if not rp.can_fetch('*', link_url):
            print "Page off limits!" 
            pass
```

Here `page` is a parsed [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) object and `url` is a URL stored as a string. The parser reads in a blank `'robots.txt'` file, instead of the one at the specified URL, and returns `True` to all `can_fetch()` queries. It looks like it's either not opening the URL or failing to read the text file.

I've tried it in the interactive interpreter, too. This is what happens, using the same syntax as the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/robotparser.html) page.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 18 2011, 18:04:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import robotparser
>>> url = 'http://www.udacity-forums.com/robots.txt'
>>> rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
>>> rp.set_url(url)
>>> rp.read()
>>> print rp

>>>
```

The line `print rp` should print the contents of the `'robots.txt'` file, but it returns blank. Even more frustrating, [these](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/robotparser/) [examples](http://effbot.org/librarybook/robotparser.htm) both work perfectly fine as written, but fail when I try my own URL. I'm pretty new to Python, and I can't figure out what's going wrong. As far as I can tell, I'm using the module in the same way as the documentation and examples. Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE 1:** Here are a few more lines from the interpreter, in case `print rp` was not a good method to check if `'robots.txt'` was read in. The `path`, `host`, and `url` attributes are correct, but the entries from `'robots.txt'` have still not been read in.

```
>>> rp
<robotparser.RobotFileParser instance at 0x1004debd8>
>>> dir(rp)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '__str__', '_add_entry', 'allow_all', 'can_fetch', 'default_entry', 'disallow_all', 'entries', 'errcode', 'host', 'last_checked', 'modified', 'mtime', 'parse', 'path', 'read', 'set_url', 'url']
>>> rp.path
'/robots.txt'
>>> rp.host
'www.udacity-forums.com'
>>> rp.entries
[]
>>> rp.url
'http://www.udacity-forums.com/robots.txt'
>>>
```

**UPDATE 2:** I have solved this problem by using [this external library](http://nikitathespider.com/python/rerp/) to parse `'robots.txt'` files. (But I haven't answered the original question!) After spending some more time in the terminal, my best guess is that `robotparser` cannot handle certain additions to the `'robots.txt'` spec, like `Sitemap`, and has trouble with blank lines. It will read in files from, e.g. Stack Overflow and Python.org, but not Google, YouTube, or my original Udacity file, which include `Sitemap` statements and blank lines. I'd still appreciate it if someone smarter than me could confirm or explain this!

Comment: By the way, you can see this snippet in context [here](https://github.com/ecmendenhall/DaveDaveFind/blob/master/crawler/udacity_crawler.py), in case I left out something relevant.

Comment: The line print rp should print the contents of the 'robots.txt' file - are you sure about that?

Comment: Pretty sure. When I used the external examples I linked, this is how it behaved. Just in case, I updated my question with some more information from the interpreter. The URL attributes all look right, but `entries` is an empty list.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I tried parsing https://www.google.com/robots.txt using the lib you mentioned (http://nikitathespider.com/python/rerp/) and when I try can_fetch("*", "/catalogs/p?") return me False, even that it's Allowed. I am in doubt here. Any clue about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using this external library to parse 'robots.txt' files. (But I haven't answered the original question!) After spending some more time in the terminal, my best guess is that robotparser cannot handle certain additions to the 'robots.txt' spec, like Sitemap, and has trouble with blank lines. It will read in files from, e.g. Stack Overflow and Python.org, but not Google, YouTube, or my original Udacity file, which include Sitemap statements and blank lines. I'd still appreciate it if someone smarter than me could confirm or explain this!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be using [reppy](https://github.com/seomoz/reppy) module

```
pip install reppy
```

Here are a few examples;

```
In [1]: import reppy

In [2]: x = reppy.fetch("http://google.com/robots.txt")

In [3]: x.atts
Out[3]: 
{'agents': {'*': <reppy.agent at 0x1fd9610>},
 'sitemaps': ['http://www.gstatic.com/culturalinstitute/sitemaps/www_google_com_culturalinstitute/sitemap-index.xml',
  'http://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xml',
  'http://www.google.com/sitemaps_webmasters.xml',
  'http://www.google.com/ventures/sitemap_ventures.xml',
  'http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sitemaps/sitemap_index.xml',
  'http://www.gstatic.com/earth/gallery/sitemaps/sitemap.xml',
  'http://www.gstatic.com/s2/sitemaps/profiles-sitemap.xml',
  'http://www.gstatic.com/trends/websites/sitemaps/sitemapindex.xml']}

In [4]: x.allowed("/catalogs/about", "My_crawler") # Should return True, since it's allowed.
Out[4]: True

In [5]: x.allowed("/catalogs", "My_crawler") # Should return False, since it's not allowed.
Out[5]: False

In [7]: x.allowed("/catalogs/p?", "My_crawler") # Should return True, since it's allowed.
Out[7]: True

In [8]: x.refresh() # Refresh robots.txt, perhaps a magic change?

In [9]: x.ttl
Out[9]: 3721.3556718826294
```

Voila!